# Not able to redirect as a post request

Tags: node.js

I am trying to redirect the user with a `post` request from the home page after checking if their `sessions` exist.

This is my home controller file:-

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session["Data"] != undefined) {
        res.redirect(307, '/Try');
    }
    else {res.render('home', {pageTitle: "Home"});}
});

module.exports = router;
```

But it is giving me error- `Cannot GET /Try`

This is what I'm using in my route file- `router.post('/Try', try_controller.Try);`

I am using `res.redirect(307, '/Try')` in another controller file of the same project and it's working. I can't figure out why it's not working here.

Comment: Where is the `/Try` route registered?

Comment: @NullDev it's registered in my route file as post.

Comment: 307 preserves the original request method. For your `/` route it is `GET` so you'll need a `router.get("/Try", ...)` handler

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect to post request in express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174857/how-to-redirect-to-post-request-in-express)

Comment: @Phil I don't want the user to access the `/Try` page without having sessions stored. So I don't think I can use `router.get()`.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, is there any solution you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried different things but in the end, I added an empty form in my home.pug file and submitted it using js.

JS code -

```
script.
    let ssn = !{JSON.stringify(session)};
    data = "Data"
        
    if (ssn[data] != undefined) {document.getElementById('form-id').submit();}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can redirect a GET as a POST. If you own the `/Try` route, one option is to add a GET handler for that, then redirect will work.

Otherwise, in your GET route handler for `\` you can create a new POST and return the results of that.

```
const request = require('request')
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session["Data"] != undefined) {
        //res.redirect(307, '/Try');
        request.post('/Try', {}, function(err, response, body) {
           if (err) return next(err)
           return res.status(response.statusCode).send(body);
        })
    }
    else {res.render('home', {pageTitle: "Home"});}
});
```

The example above an https://github.com/request/request though there are more modern ways of sending POST from express.

This isn't technically "redirecting", so you won't return 307 or 302.

Comment: The above code is giving me an error saying `Error: Invalid URI "/Try"`

Comment: @Avi -- Is a route handler implemented for that route,  `router.post('/Try', function(req, res, next) { .... })` ?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have a router file for it.